# Open .NET Plugin in Tab

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, plugins

I am creating a Visual Studio .NET plugin using DXCore for my group to use and have been trying to figure out how to open the plugin in a tab like source control does instead of it opening in a new window. Any Ideas how this can be done???

Comment: Do you mean a Visual Studio plugin?

Answer (score 1):

If you create the plug-in as a "Tool Window" plug-in, you should be able to dock the created window in the normal docking locations in VS.Net

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by creating a ToolWindowPlugin and a StandardPlugin. Once the ToolWindowPlugin is accessable from the Menu Bar, you can programatically call it from a Keystroke event on the StandardPlugin.

There is a good example of this in the dxCore Community Plugins CR_WorkBench project
http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/source/browse/trunk/CR_WorkBench/?r=156

**References:**
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q205791.aspx